# Mapnik Blue Tiles with TileCache

Tags: mapping, openstreetmap, mapnik

I am still trying to get my server running OpenStreetMap. I have TileCache and Mapnik installed. I have an extract of the U.S. state of Oklahoma imported into my database. I have used OSM Mapnik tools to create an XML stylesheet and I have confirmed that 'generate_image.py' makes a nice map image. I have (at least I believe I have) granted PostGIS access properly. My user has full permissions over all of the tables in the database. When I look in the Apache logs, all I see are notes about cache misses (I used to see database connection issues, but I don't any more). In the Postgres logs, I don't see anything (again, I used to see access denied issues, but I don't anymore). Despite all of this, when I ask TileCache to render a tile from the OSM Mapnik layer, all I get is this image:

[image: Mapnik Rendered Tile]

This image shows up no matter where I am on the map or what zoom level I am at. I have TileCache running under CGI and it has a configuration like this:

```
[osm]
type=Mapnik
mapfile=/var/maps/bin/mapnik/osm.xml
spherical_mercator=true
```

I am using OpenLayers and my Javascript looks like this:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
var vec = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("TC", "http://maps.company.com/cgi-bin/tilecache/tilecache.cgi/", {serviceVersion: "1.0.0", layername: "osm", type: "png"});
map.addLayer(vec);
```

I have been working on this server for two and a half weeks. I have read every blog, forum, or other post I can find. This is my third question today. I am getting desperate. I would really appreciate any help anybody has.

Comment: You need to make sure your OpenLayers Map is in Spherical Mercator projection. You can do this by passing an options hash as an argument to the Map constructor.

Comment: Would that explain why I can manually request a tile and still get a blue tile?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea why, but things started working last night. It must have been something with OpenLayers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that you have valid data in postgis? Opening up the data in Quantum GIS is a good way to check.

Comment: I have used 'generate_image.py' and gotten an image that has the 'world_boundary' base map images with OSM data for Oklahoma overtop. The Oklahoma OSM data was imported into the database from an extract .osm file.

Comment: I have just opened up stuff in Quantum GIS and everything looks good there too.

Comment: okay. just be aware that the osm.xml stylesheets use both shapefiles and data from postgis.

Comment: I am aware of that. I should have the full set of shapefiles required for OSM and Mapnik.